# How do I fix my sortData and compareTo method. I keep receiving "cannot be converted to error."

Tags: java

I keep receiving error: incompatible types: BingoPlayer cannot be converted to BingoPlayer[] when I try to pass to arrays to my compareTo method. I am not really sure how to fix the issue.

I am reading data from a text file. Here are the contents of that file:

- 50.00
- 10
- James,Smith,50.0
- Michael,Smith,50.0
- Robert,Smith,50.0
- Maria,Garcia,50.0
- David,Smith,50.0
- Maria,Rodriguez,50.0
- Mary,Smith,50.0
- Maria,Hernandez,50.0
- Maria,Martinez,50.0
- James,Clapper,50.0

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

```
public static void sortData()
{
    int n = test.length;
    int m =0;
    BingoPlayer temp;  
     for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
     {  
        for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++)
        {  
            m = compareTo((test[j], test[j+1];
           if(m > 0)
           {  
             temp = test[j-1];  
             test[j-1] = test[j];  
             test[j] = temp;  
           }  

        }  
     }  

}
public static int compareTo(BingoPlayer[] player1, BingoPlayer[] player2)
{
    for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            if(player1[i].firstName.compareTo(player2[i].firstName) != 0)
                return player1[i].firstName.compareTo((player2[i].firstName));
            else if (player1[i].lastName.compareTo(player2[i].lastName) != 0)
                return player1[i].lastName.compareTo((player2[i].lastName));
            else 
                return player1[i].lastName.compareTo(player2[i].lastName);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I think you need to normalize your data. All your lines have first name, last name, double. But your first two lines have a double and integer. It might be that that causes the issue, because all lines don't match up, and you haven't shown how you read the file. Just try to compare all the data with the first two lines left out. See if that helps.

Comment: Your `compareTo` function is expecting two arrays of `BingoPlayers`, but it seems like you're passing two `BingoPlayer` objects instead of full arrays. Not 100% sure though because your question doesn't show what `test[]` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compare method should take two BingoPlayer object, not array of those.

You should also read about Comparable and Comparator interfaces.

EDIT: There is some snippet with Comparable and Comparator implementation

```
class BingoPlayer implements Comparable<BingoPlayer> {

    // rest of your class
    String firstName, lastName;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BingoPlayer player) {
        if(firstName.compareTo(player.firstName) != 0)
            return firstName.compareTo((player.firstName));
        else if (lastName.compareTo(player.lastName) != 0)
            return lastName.compareTo((player.lastName));
        else
            return lastName.compareTo(player.lastName);
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
player1.compareTo(player2);
```

Other way is create own Comparator class:

```
class BingoPlayerComparator implements Comparator<BingoPlayer> {

    @Override
    public int compare(BingoPlayer player1, BingoPlayer player2) {
        if(player1.firstName.compareTo(player2.firstName) != 0)
            return player1.firstName.compareTo((player2.firstName));
        else if (player1.lastName.compareTo(player2.lastName) != 0)
            return player1.lastName.compareTo((player2.lastName));
        else 
            return player1.lastName.compareTo(player2.lastName);
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
BingoPlayerComparator c = new BingoPlayerComparator();
c.compare(player1, player2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't provide all of your code, I am going to assume "test" is an array of BingoPlayer objects.

I suggest that you change your compareTo method to only compare 1 BingoPlayer with another BingoPlayer. With the way that your code works you are comparing everything in test and then calling a method which compares everything in test again. Let's reduce the redundancy and try to make this work:

```
public static void sortData()
{
    int n = test.length;
    int m =0;
    BingoPlayer temp;  
     for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
     {  
        for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++)
        {  
            m = compareTo((test[j], test[j+1];
           if(m > 0)
           {  
             temp = test[j-1];  
             test[j-1] = test[j];  
             test[j] = temp;  
           }  

        }  
     }  

}
public static int compareTo(BingoPlayer player1, BingoPlayer player2)
{

            if(player1.firstName.compareTo(player2.firstName) != 0)
                return player1.firstName.compareTo((player2.firstName));
            else if (player1.lastName.compareTo(player2.lastName) != 0)
                return player1.lastName.compareTo((player2.lastName));
            else 
                return player1.lastName.compareTo(player2.lastName);

}

}
```

Again, I had to assume that "test" was an array of BingoPlayer objects. If that is the case, then you were trying to send two single BingoPlayer objects to a method that was expecting two BingoPlayer arrays. Making the change to your compareTo that I show above should fix your program.